# gdk (gtk3) in codeblocks on windows 7

Tags: c++, c, windows, gtk3, gdk

I have configured gtk3+ (I've changed gtk2+ to gtk3+)   in codeblocks 13.2 on windows 7,
and created new gtk+ (exmaple) project. This example projcet was compiled and works properly.

Next I included gdk:

```
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
```

But when I added the lines:

```
gdk_init(&argc, &argv);

GdkScreen *screen = gdk_screen_get_default();`
```

I got 2 errors:

> undefined referrence to 'gdk_init' and
>   undefined referrence to 'gdk_screen_get_default'

Where is the problem? I'm looking for a concrete solution.

compilation log:

```
||=== Build: Debug in gtk4test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\myp\gtk4test\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\myp\gtk4test\main.c|37|warning: 'gtk_vbox_new' is deprecated (declared at C:\gtk\include\gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkvbox.h:60): Use 'gtk_box_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\myp\gtk4test\main.c|53|warning: unused variable 'screen' [-Wunused-variable]|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\myp\gtk4test\main.c|52|undefined reference to `gdk_init'|
C:\myp\gtk4test\main.c|53|undefined reference to `gdk_screen_get_default'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Please show your compilation statement. Most probably, you're missing to link with the required library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already called gtk_init, then you shouldn't call gdk_init (as gtk_init also calls it). Generally, you should just call the gdk functions.

If you need gdk_init() for some reason, you will have to add

```
gcc ... `pkg-config --libs --cflags  gdk-3.0` ...
```

to the compilation line. Note that you probably also have to reconfigure your IDE to use gdk3 instead of gdk2.